# Blank page for virtual host and unclickable http link for subfolder project in wampserver

Tags: wamp, wampserver, wamp64

I've just installed wamp on my 64bit windows laptop. The icon is green and the localhost home page opens fine. I followed troubleshooting for blank pages regarding port 80, skype etc. I've also followed instructions for setting up the virtualhost for my project, which is in a subfolder in the www folder in my wamp installation.

The BirkeloArtDemo link in my Your Projects menu remains unclickable as an http link.

But more importantly, when I click on BirkeloArtDemo under my Your VirtualHost submenu, I get an essentially blank page rather than the website content.

Before I set up the virtual host, it was showing an entirely blank page at the subfolder address. Now that the virtual host is set up, I get a a blank page with a small square and line in the top left corner of the browser window.

I'm running out of ways to troubleshoot whatever's going on, so that I can see and edit my website locally between Dreamweaver and wamp and don't have to actively upload and be online to preview changes.

[localhost homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwTut.jpg)

[virtualhost homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGyrg.jpg)

Comment: Did you place any files in the DocumentRoot folder for the new Virtual Host?

Comment: Specifically an `index.php` file?

Comment: `The BirkeloArtDemo link in my Your Projects menu remains unclickable as an http link.` That is supposed to happen

Comment: I have a site that's going to be wordpress based and php that I'll be working on with wamp. But this particular project is a simple html site. The page is index.html. I'm guessing I'm being clueless and that wamp won't work with that?